# how do I convert this sql query (active record) into the correct timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

```
@interactions_by_time = @report.interactions.where(interaction_type: "comment").select('EXTRACT(HOUR from interaction_time)').group('EXTRACT(HOUR FROM interaction_time)').count.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
```

I have the active record query above, which basically groups interactions by the time they occured (hour). However, the result is something like this:

```
[[23.0, 23], [2.0, 17], [21.0, 16], [20.0, 11], [1.0, 11], [0.0, 9], [22.0, 7], [18.0, 5], [3.0, 5], [4.0, 4], [5.0, 4], [19.0, 4], [12.0, 3], [15.0, 3], [16.0, 2], [14.0, 1], [17.0, 1], [11.0, 1], [10.0, 1], [13.0, 1]]
```

This is in UTC time however, how do I make sure this is in whatever time the current_user is in?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CONVERT_TZ  function to take the datetime and convert it from one timezone to another: (as an offset of UTC)

`CONVERT_TZ(status_changes.created_at, '+00:00', '+08:00')`

or convert it from the stored value (UTC) to a local timezone like (PST).

`CONVERT_TZ(status_changes.created_at,'UTC',?) between ? and ?, 'PST, '2014-01-24', '2014-03-10'`

You could then allow the user to select their timezone and match the conversions to their specific timezone.